# Determining the Norm and Compactness of an Operator in Banach Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\{X_n\}$ be a sequence of Banach spaces and $X = \bigoplus_{p} X_n$ their direct sum. For operators $A_n \in B(X_n)$ with bounded supremum $\sup_n \|A_n\| < \infty$, we define an operator $A: X \to X$ by $A\{x_n\} = \{A_nx_n\}$. Show that $\|A\| = \sup_n \|A_n\|$. Additionally, prove that $A \in K(X)$ if and only if each $A_n \in K(X)$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \|A_n\| = 0$.

This problem is taken from [Conway, Page 217, #3]. The space $K(X)$ denotes the set of all compact operators on $X$, that is, operators that map bounded sets to relatively compact sets, or equivalently, the closure of the image of any bounded set is compact.

For the second part: Show that $A \in K(X)$ if and only if each $A_n \in K(X)$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \|A_n\| = 0$. While the sufficiency part seems approachable by considering the properties of compact operators and the limit condition, I am looking for an explanation or proof for this part, particularly for the necessity. Any guidance or proof outlines would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I guess the norm in the direct sum is the sum of the norms.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Could you clarify a bit? The first part is to show that $\|A\| = \sup_n \|A_n\|$. Any ideas to do the second part? @RyszardSzwarc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_n\in X_n$ satisfy $$\|x_n\|=1,\quad \|A_nx_n\|\ge {1\over 2}\|A_n\|$$ Consider the sequence $v^{(n)}\in X$ defined by $$v^{(n)}_k=\begin{cases}A_nx_n & k=n\\ 0 & k\neq n\end{cases}$$ Then $\|v^{(n)}\|=\|A_nx_n\|\le \| A_n\|.$ The sequence is thus bounded. For $n\neq m$ we have $$\|Av^{(n)}-Av^{(m)}\| \ge \max(\|A_nx_n\|,\|A_mx_m\|)\ge {1 \over 2}\max(\|A_n\|,\|A_m\|)$$ Assume by contradiction that $\|A_n\|\not\to 0.$ Thus there exists $\delta>0$ and  a sequence $n_k$ such  that $\|A_{n_k}\|\ge \delta.$ Then for $k\neq l$ we get $$\|Av^{(n_k)}-Av^{(n_l)}\|\ge {1\over 2}\delta$$ This implies that the sequence $\{Av^{(n_k)}\}_{k=1}^\infty$ has no accumulation point.

Comment: Could you explain how "$\|Av^{(n)}-Av^{(m)}\| \ge \max(\|A_nx_n\|,\|A_mx_m\|)\ge {1 \over 2}\max(\|A_n\|,\|A_m\|)$" implies the last statement "For $n\neq m$ we have $$\|Av^{(n)}-Av^{(m)}\| \ge \max(\|A_nx_n\|,\|A_mx_m\|)\ge {1 \over 2}\max(\|A_n\|,\|A_m\|)$$ Any subsequence of $Av^{(n)}$ contains a convergent subsequence iff $\|A_n\|\to 0.$"?

Comment: I have re-edited to clarify the last sentence